# Android : Window couldn't find content container view after adding file in raw folder

Tags: android, containers, wear-os, android-6.0-marshmallow

Am getting an **Window couldn't find content container view**. This error asking when the app is going to checking the permission

I noticed that for the wear app , am copying the wear apk into the raw folder.
Its having around 2.5 Mb. After adding this am getting this crash

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Window couldn't find content container view
 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4614)
 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4683)
 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2263)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4276)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Try the workaround in this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207638) if it is applicable in your case. They solve this kind of error by using this workaround. Within your Activity's `onCreate()` method, add a call to `getWindow().getDecorView()` prior to calling `super.onCreate()` (which comes before the call to `setContentView()`).

Answer (score 3):

Comscore library was causing this issue in my case. Try removing it.

Comment: I had the same issue, and found that version 5.2.0 of the Comscore SDK was causing the problem. Upgrading to 5.3.1 (released a few days ago) seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Where did you get version 5.3.1 from? I just checked https://github.com/comScore/ComScore-Android
but latest version there is still 5.2

Comment: It may not be listed there, but it's available on the maven repository. Check it out at http://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/comscore/android-analytics/maven-metadata.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37095334)
add a call to `getWindow().getDecorView()` prior to calling `super.onCreate()`